# Verify URL is direct image URL from Bing Search API?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, api, bing

I'm trying to use Bing Search API to allow users to assocaiate bing images with a post inline on the website, once they select an image from there search it saves it to the server for use.. But sometimes with Bing Search Results the 'MediaUrl' returned isn't nessecarily an image.

**Example 1) Searching Keyword `Nascar`**
Returns two images:
1) www.betbigdc.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/nascar1.jpg <- actually is image and i can work with, works in `<img src=''>`.
2) http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/23900000/NASCAR-nascar-23962589-425-425.jpg .. that url actually loads to www.fanpop.com/clubs/nascar/images/23962589/title/nascar-photo?ir=true..

**Example 2) Searching Keyword `Jason Aldean`**
Returns two images:
1) www.greenobles.com/data_images/jason-aldean/jason-aldean-01.jpg <- actual image url that works in `<img src=''>`.
2) http://www.cmtradiolive.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/jason-aldean.jpg funny url that actually loads a web page.

```
<?php
// Search Bing Api 
$articles = sitesearch('Jason Aldean', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $accountKey, 4);
$i        = 0;
// Process Results starting with reszing image within aspect ration to display to user
foreach ($articles['d']['results'] as $article) {
    $i++;

    $dimensions    = array(
        $article['Width'],
        $article['Height']
    );
    $dimensionsNew = array(
        125,
        125
    );

    // What scale do we need to go to
    $scaleRequired = min($dimensionsNew[0] / $dimensions[0], $dimensionsNew[1] / $dimensions[1]);

    if ($scaleRequired < 1) {
        $twidth  = $dimensions[0] * $scaleRequired;
        $theight = $dimensions[1] * $scaleRequired;

        // Resize to $finalDimensions

    } else {
        $twidth  = $article['Width'];
        $theight = $article['Height'];
    }
    // Display images resized within ration to =< 125PX
    echo "<img alt='bimage' width='$twidth' height='$theight' src='" . $article['MediaUrl'] . "' style='magin:     10px !important; 
       border: thin solid #666666;' />&nbsp;&nbsp;";

}
?>
```

### Is there any way to verify a given url is or is not an direct image url?!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to verify a given url is or is not an direct image
>   url?!

You can also do analyze the response itself. It would look like so:

```
/**
 *
 * @return boolean Whether image is "pure"
 */
function is_image_url($url, array $extensions){

    $response = get_headers($url, 1);

    foreach($response as $key => $value){

         foreach($extension as $ext){

              if (stripos($value, $ext) !== FALSE){
                  return TRUE;
              }
         }
   }

   return FALSE;
}

//Usage:

$extensions = array('jpg', 'gif', 'bmp');

if ( is_image_url('http://exampe.com/image.jpg', $extensions) === TRUE ){
   // It is. Do some stuff here
}
```

Comment: Wow, i didn't know there's a `get_headers` function, this is far more better than my verbose `curl` solution. Up vote!

Comment: @LotusH actually curl is a bit faster according to my tests. `get_headers()` should be used as a "last chance", say, for example, when curl isn't installed or user does not want to grasp the one.

Comment: I just read the doc of `get_headers`, and I think you have to set a second parameter `1` for `get_headers` to set keys for the return value or the result would be indexed by nubers ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `curl` to determine this.

1. When initializing, set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to `false` in `curl_setopt` to let `curl` not follow redirect.
2. `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `true` to include the return header information.
3. Judge whether there's a `Location` header set.
4. For URLs like http://www.cmtradiolive.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/jason-aldean.jpg that directly lead you to another content without jump, you can judge by `Content-type` in the return header to see if the content is an image or not.

Detail about `curl`: [http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)